# Pages are scrollable after reaching a footer

Tags: layout, template, magento2.4.2, rwd, footer

Just noticed that Responsive Web Design doesn't work correctly for a desktop version of website. After reaching a footer with page scrolling, pages of website can be scrolled far further (just scrolling through empty space to the page end). At the same time, for a mobile version everything works fine, page is not scrollable after reaching a footer.

It doesn't matter whether I use native Magento Luma or other theme. The result is the same.

How this issue can be fixed?

Will be grateful for any help.

**1. A desktop version:**

[image]

**2. A mobile version:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

**OK, I found a bug.** It is simple. Look at your menu: Телефони -> Недорогі мобільні телефони -> submenu (its height is above 11k px!!!).

You have to change your styles, something like that:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .subchildmenu .subchildmenu {
      max-height: 300px;
      overflow: auto;
  }
}
```

That's mean your submenu's submenu will have max-height 300px and scrollbar will appear (because overflow: auto).

Consider whether you should also set the maximum height for the first sub-menu to avoid such a situation in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Still can't find anything suspicious in CSS.  How I can correct this footer margin with theme's custom CSS in Admin panel. F.e. example I can fix a footer position with such lines of code:


.page-footer {
    position: fixed;
}

Comment: It's seems like there is not enough content on the page. I just need to auto-adjust page height to an available content.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this store?

Comment: [link](https://m2.backendlforum.xyz/)

A mobile version works fine. The problem appears with a desktop version.

Comment: I edited my first answear, check this out ;)

Comment: Oh! These were just dummy categories for testing purposes in Телефони -> Недорогі мобільні телефони. And it's appeared that they broke a style :) Final version of the website's menu will not include this level of categories at all. Though I fixed the issue with your code for both: dummy categories and its parent category. 

Your help is priceless! Thank you very much ;)